# System cannot execute the specified program/"cpuminer-64 is not recognized as an internal operable program or batch file"

Tags: windows-8

I downloaded a program off the Internet and am trying to run it in Command Prompt. However, Windows says, "The system cannot execute the specified program." I'm not sure why this is happening, because I'm an administrator. Someone else suggested that I right-click the file and click "Unblock" under "Properties," but I could not find this button. The program is cpuminer-x64, but I am not aware of any possible causes related to that program.

I am running Windows 8 64-bit.

Edit: After cding to the directory of the program, I get the following error:

"cpuminer-64.exe is not recognized as an internal operable program or batch file"

I am also not running any anti-virus software.

Comment: Have you tried this Windows 7 hotfix? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2719305/the-system-cannot-execute-the-specified-program-error-message-and-appl just check to see if your computer ifts the description.

Comment: The name `cpuminer-x64` makes me suspect that it is a 64-bit program. Is your operating system 64-bit?

Comment: @Scott: Yes, it is.

Comment: @RaghuRanganathan: I'm running windows 8.

Comment: check to see if your antivirus is blocking the program... many cryptocurrency miners have been flagged as harmful.

Comment: @druge: No, not running antivirus.